# Replacing ',' with '.' in CSV file with python 2.5.1

Tags: python, csv

I am a newbie to python and have been facing issues with .csv file editing with python 2.5.1 version.

My aim is to replace all ',' with '.' in the csv data.

here is how far i could get.

```
import csv
import re

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

f_dic = {',':'.'}

with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    text=f.read()

with open('file+.csv','w') as w:
    text=replace_all(text,f_dic)
    print text
    w.write(text)
```

when i run it shows - with 'open'  as invalid syntax.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: How can you replace ',' in CSV data? How do you know which is a separator value and which is in your data?

Comment: Probably better to use `cvs` to load it with the one deliminator, then save it with the other, instead of using `replace`

Comment: @Ron E the data in the csv file is stored according to german standards which means ',' is used instead of '.' and in this case ';' is used as a separator.

Comment: @user3181928 Ah silly Germans, then just open the file as text as I suggested in my answer. There's no need to tokenize it as a CSV if you are not modifying or using the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your syntax error, in Python 2.5, you need:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

to use the `with` statement. It's only available by default in Python 2.6 and later.

Note that you don't use the `csv` and `re` modules that you import. `re` is unnecessary, but if you care about quoting and escaping, you probably want to read the file with the normal defaults for a csv reader and write with the delimiter '.' instead of simply replacing things. Your code as written will only work if there are no `.`s in your existing data, and no escaped or quoted `,`s that shouldn't be converted. Depending on how you're going to use the file, naming it "something.csv" may also be a Bad Idea since it's no longer actual comma-separated data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change the delimiter from comma to period. If this is the case then no need to open as csv, simply open as text and replace all the ','

```
with open('file.csv', w) as fp:
    text = f.read()
    text.replace(',' , '.')
    fp.tell(0);
    fp.write(text)
```